# Dynamic height for html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a web page with basic template.

It has a header, top navigation, side navigation, main content area and footer.

I created a similar design in jsfiddle, though it looks different from what I see in my html. Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/f4sc9sy7/8/

Here is my code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".top-menu").click(function(e){

  // set selectd menu as active
  $(".top-menu").removeClass("active");

     $(this).addClass("active");
  });

  // main view area height
  var footerHeight = $("footer").outerHeight();
  var headerHeight = $("header").outerHeight();
  var menuHeight = $("#top-nav").outerHeight();
  var htmlHeight = $("html").outerHeight();

  var mainWindowHeight = htmlHeight - (footerHeight + headerHeight + menuHeight);

 //how to remove this hard coding?
  $("#main-layout").outerHeight(mainWindowHeight-41);


});
```

```css
html {
  background: #F5F4EF;
  color: #000305;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;

}

#side-nav {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: inherit;
  background: lavender;
}

#main-content {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  height: inherit;
  background: lightgreen;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: #F5F4EF;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 0;
}

#top-nav {
  width: auto;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Test HomePage </title>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>
<header>
 <h1> Header </h1>
</header>
<div id="top-nav" class="topnav"> 
 <a class="top-menu" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a class="top-menu" href="#news">News</a>
  <a class="top-menu" href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a class="top-menu" href="#about">About</a>
</div>
<div id="main-layout">

  <div id="side-nav">
    Side Navigation
  </div>

  <div id="main-content">
    content
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <h1>Footer </h1>
</footer>
```

There are two issues:

1. I am trying to set height of main content div dynamically. I wish to use javascript and relative attributes to set the height of page. Due to some unknown reason, there are gaps between the elements( possibly due to margin or padding). How to remove this?
2. How to make this html cross browser, such that it works on all major browsers?

Thanks

**Update** : I have updated my stylesheet. Removed javascript code for height setting. Here is the updated link: https://jsfiddle.net/f4sc9sy7/9/.

This now looks closed to expected layout. Now there is just one problem of total html height. It is going beyond the browser height, not sure how to correct it.

Here is the css code:

```
html {
  background: #F5F4EF;
  color: #000305;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
height: 100%;
}

body{height: 100%;}

#side-nav {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lavender;
}

#main-content {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: #F5F4EF;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 0;
}

H1 { margin:0; }

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}


#main-layout{
height: 90%;
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: In general, try to only use CSS to manage style, layout and flow. Having a mix of style being applied between CSS and JavaScript will become unmanageable in the long run and can at worst start interfering with each other's instructions.

Comment: To remove space between elements you need to remove margin from H1. `H1 { margin:0; }`. This will cause an issue with the size of `main-layout` because the height will be negative. How high should be `main-layout`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added the margin:0. It removed the gap. My objective is to make the make the layout dynamic. I am using css to control the look and feel and using javascript to control element space. Is my css conflicting with javascript code?

Comment: While this might not apply to small projects, but relevant, after having worked on large scale projects, JavaScript should worry about functionality and CSS about styles, look and feel. UI designers should be able to add/remove classes as needed without JavaScript functionality breaking, hence they don't use id selectors or attributes as those can change any time by front-end devs. Same other way around, front-end devs don't use class selectors as classes could change any time by UI designers. There will be exception off course. Separation of concern is always important and good practice IMHO.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Will try to update all look and feel attributes with css.

Comment: Removed javascript now. Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/f4sc9sy7/9/. The main body is expanding beyond browser height.

Comment: How can I control the overall page height? Now this is the only thing that is remaining. I tried setting html height = 100%. but it did not fix the issue. I wish to keep it relative so that any resolution works on this page.

Answer (score 0):

add `height:100%;` to your html

```
html {
  background: #F5F4EF;
  color: #000305;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height:100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLnx0y2o/1/)

Comment: In jsfiddle, I see the change. But in my webpage, I do not see any difference.

Comment: if you can share the link of your webpage, I can help or just post the full css here

Comment: Here is the style block: 

html {
  background: #F5F4EF;
  color: #000305;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}
#side-nav {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: inherit;
  background: lavender;
}
#main-content {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  height: inherit;
  background: lightgreen;
}
header,footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: #F5F4EF;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 0;
}
H1 { margin:0; }
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

Comment: i meant the other css if any, anyways looking at this piece of code it should work fine but if you are facing issues inspect the dom in chrome and check html height

Answer (score -1):

```
#main-layout {
  min-height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Applying this to the jsfiddle increases he height of the content covering the footer

Comment: thanks for the reply, I added it to my html, but it did not reflect any changes.

Comment: footer h1{ margin-top:0px;}